# R: Conditional summing in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have an R data frame with many columns, and I want to sum only columns (header: score) having cell value >25 under row named "Matt". The sum value can be placed after the last column.

```
input (df1)
```

| Name | score | score | score | score | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alex | 31 | 15 | 18 | 22 | 23 |
| Pat | 37 | 18 | 29 | 15 | 28 |
| Matt | 33 | 27 | 18 | 88 | 9 |
| James | 12 | 36 | 32 | 13 | 21 |

```
output (df2)
```

| Name | score | score | score | score | score | Matt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alex | 31 | 15 | 18 | 22 | 23 | 68 |
| Pat | 37 | 18 | 59 | 55 | 28 | 110 |
| Matt | 33 | 27 | 18 | 88 | 9 | 148 |
| James | 12 | 36 | 32 | 13 | 21 | 61 |

Any thoughts are more than welcome,

Regards,

Comment: The second row values are changed in df1 and df2 i.e. score 3rd column in input was 29 vs 59 and score 4 values are 15 vs 55

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to extract the row where 'Name' is 'Matt', without the first column create a logical vector ('i1'), use that to subset the columns and get the `rowSums`

```
i1 <- df1[df1$Name == "Matt",-1] > 25
df1$Matt <- rowSums(df1[-1][,i1], na.rm = TRUE)
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   mutate(Matt = rowSums(select(cur_data(), 
            where(~ is.numeric(.) && .[Name == 'Matt'] > 25))))
```

-output

```
#   Name score score.1 score.2 score.3 score.4 Matt
#1  Alex    31      15      18      22      23   68
#2   Pat    37      18      29      15      28   70
#3  Matt    33      27      18      88       9  148
#4 James    12      36      32      13      21   61
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Name = c("Alex", "Pat", "Matt", "James"), score = c(31L, 
37L, 33L, 12L), score.1 = c(15L, 18L, 27L, 36L), score.2 = c(18L, 
29L, 18L, 32L), score.3 = c(22L, 15L, 88L, 13L), score.4 = c(23L, 
28L, 9L, 21L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Thank you Arun. It is working but just I have a small question as I have few negative values and if I want to also consider the values which are below to -25 (>-25) then which function I need to change. I am sending you the dataframe. condition: sum column cell If Matt row value >25 or >-25. The input and output is given below.

Comment: Input_df1 <- structure(list(Name = c("Alex", "Pat", "Matt", "James"), score = c(31L, 37L, 33L, 12L), score.1 = c(15L, 18L, 27L, -36L), score.2 = c(18L, 29L, 18L, 32L), score.3 = c(22L, 15L, 88L, 13L), score.4 = c(23L, 28L, 9L, 21L), score.5 = c(23L, 28L, -19L, 21L), score.6 = c(23L, -28L, -29L, 21L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

Comment: output_df2 <- structure(list(Name = c("Alex", "Pat", "Matt", "James"), score = c(31L, 37L, 33L, 12L), score.1 = c(15L, 18L, 27L, -36L), score.2 = c(18L, 29L, 18L, 32L), score.3 = c(22L, 15L, 88L, 13L), score.4 = c(23L, 28L, 9L, 21L), score.5 = c(23L, 28L, -19L, 21L), score.6 = c(23L, -28L, -29L, 21L), sum = c(91L, 42L, 119L, 10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It is working as needed. Actually, I was using pandas but it was taking huge time to complete. I have no words to express my gratitudes. Thanks bro.

Comment: Sure, I will be careful next time.

Comment: I can understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the code below

```
df$Matt <- rowSums(df[-1] * (df[df$Name == "Matt", -1] > 25)[rep(1, nrow(df)), ])
```

which gives

```
> df
   Name score score score score score Matt
1  Alex    31    15    18    22    23   68
2   Pat    37    18    29    15    28   70
3  Matt    33    27    18    88     9  148
4 James    12    36    32    13    21   61
```

Comment: Thank you, Thomas. It is working as needed. Thanks